# Javascript equivalent of HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack

In WebPack I can use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to build an HTML "front door" to my web app.

If WebPack has built chunks with dynamic filenames like `runtime.384756.js`, `main.283746.js`, then these will be injected into the HTML as:

```
<script src="runtime.384756.js"/>
<script src="main.283746.js"/>
```

But, I want a JS file to be the "front door" of what I serve. (The use case is a micro-frontend: a different site contains the HTML that calls my JS with a single `<script>` tag.

I can disable chunking, and generate a huge `main.js` which my client can link to.

But I'd the `.js` file they link to to be a small one (so it can be cheaply served without caching), which then loads the larger chunks. Functionally identical to loading the single-file version, but potentially more cache-friendly behind the scenes.

I'm not giving an example of what that tiny `.js` file would look like, because I'm not sure what it would be: `import` statements? Something more kludgy, but compatible with more browsers?

How can I get WebPack to build such a JS file?

Comment: Do i understand correctly that instead of the html being served to the localhost address you want the plain / compiled js to be served ?

Comment: If thats the case, just remove the plugins content from the webpack config.

Comment: @OliverIlmjärv Yes, but I also want the "well known" JS file that my clients link to, to cause the browser to load up all the chunks, with their webpack-generated names.